# Using personalize view adds "filter this visual" in power BI

Tags: powerbi

The "total count" in the Report only works if the filters are applied on page level (or higher). When adding fields through Personalize View, then a new filter is added for "this visual". By using that filter, the "total count" is not updated and it might confuse users.

need to check whether this can be avoided in any way to make the tool easier to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have used card in my dashboard to show total count of rows in the table.  If as a end user I add any new field in the filter pane it automatically goes to "filter on this visual", due to which change in total count on the card is not reflected